# Angular PWA Dynamic API value

Tags: angular, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, angular8, angular-service-worker

I have a problem as I cached all the data of my app in service workers.

Still, the problem is my header, and footer comes from a dynamic API accordion to localization Value.

The header and footer component is not a part of the cached app and depends on compelling value to set the style.

Could you provide me with any possible solutions?